# Connect Node js Project to Microsoft Teams

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I want to send an error message to a particular group or person from Microsoft teams. For which I want to connect my project which is running daily basis

How can I Connect all these and send a customize message for that error in teams

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your ask?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can use a incoming webhook endpoint to send messages in Teams channel:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#:~:text=To%20add%20an%20Incoming%20Webhook%20to%20a%20Teams,webhook%20URL%20present%20in%20the%20dialog%20window.%20